# Problems with converting buffer to JS object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mqtt

I'm using the [mosca](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca) library for a MQTT broker and [this](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca) for MQTT client.

The client code looks like this:

```
client.on('connect', function () {
client.subscribe('presence')
var json = {
  someVar: 888,
  someNum: 234 
}
client.publish('presence', JSON.stringify(json));
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  var json = JSON.parse(message.toString())
  console.log(json.someVar);
  client.end();
});
```

The broker, where each published message is handled is here:

```
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Package received:')
  console.log('Published', packet);

  var stringBuf = packet.payload.toString('utf-8')
  console.log('buffer to string:', stringBuf)
  var stringify = JSON.stringify(packet.payload)
  console.log('stringify:',stringify);
  var json = JSON.parse(stringily);
}
```

The output for `buffer to string:` looks like this:
`{"someVar":888,"someNum":234}`
Which should be valid json. But whenever I try to access the json-object (after using `JSON.parse()`) it just returns undefined for the variables.

I've also tried to do

```
var buf = json.data;
console.log('buffer data:', but);
```

But that just returns a buffer array, which can't seem to convert either.

In the client function I can easily parse the string to a JS object, so I'm a bit lost as to what is happening.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this `var stringify = JSON.stringify(packet.payload)`? Just `JSON.parse(stringBuf)` and you'll have your object.

Comment: When I do that I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like *stdob--* said, you're trying to parse all incoming messages, example of output for your example:

```
Package received:
Published mqttjs_05cac308
Package received:
Published {"clientId":"mqttjs_05cac308","topic":"presence"}
Package received:
Published <Buffer 7b 22 73 6f 6d 65 56 61 72 22 3a 38 38 38 2c 22 73 6f 6d 65 4e 75 6d 22 3a 32 33 34 7d>
Package received:
Published {"clientId":"mqttjs_05cac308","topic":"presence"}
Package received:
Published mqttjs_05cac308
```

You can check for the topic to handle the `presence` message you need:

```
server.on('published', function (packet, client) {
    if (packet.topic == 'presence') {
        var stringBuf = packet.payload.toString('utf-8');
        var obj = JSON.parse(stringBuf);
        console.log(obj);
    }
});
/* output: { someVar: 888, someNum: 234 } */
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive an error because tries to parse all incoming messages, including service messages that do not contain the pure JSON data. Try this:

```
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Package received:')
  console.log('Published', packet);

  var stringBuf = packet.payload.toString('utf-8')
  try {
    var json = JSON.parse(stringBuf);
    console.log( json );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log( stringBuf );
  }
}
```